# ManuelBastioni addon

Tags: add-on

I recently got a new computer, and all my Blender addons are gone. One addon I can't get it is ManuelBastioni lab, because the site is under construction.

So does anyone have the .zip file of the addon, I would be really happy if you could share it.

Comment: This site is not for this, but here you are https://github.com/animate1978/MB-Lab

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the original add-on has been discontinued. However, there's a community supported branch of the add-on available at https://github.com/animate1978/MB-Lab/wiki

Comment: I have this problem https://i.imgur.com/pYzJ3KP.png

Comment: The latest version of MB supports Blender 2.8 but 2.8 includes some changes that mean add-ons aren’t compatible with versions of Blender prior to 2.8. I think to use it on 2.79 you’ll need an earlier version downloadable from here : https://github.com/animate1978/MB-Lab/releases/tag/1.6.5b